# Changing onclicklistener for a button from radio buttons

Tags: java, android, radio-button, onclicklistener

Hi im trying to make 3 radio buttons change onclick listener for a button each radiobutton sets its own on click listener for that button.
but i get 
(MainActivity is not an enclosing class)

Note: the radiobuttons are in settings activity and the button is in mainactivity.

**Settings**

```
public class Settings extends MainActivity {

private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private RadioButton radioButtonpc;
private RadioButton radioButtonps;
private RadioButton radioButtonxb;
public Button settings;
public Button cheatsactivity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    cheatsactivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cheats_activity);
    settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setting_btn);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    radioButtonpc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    radioButtonxb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    radioButtonps = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

    radioButtonpc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cheatsactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PC.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    radioButtonxb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cheatsactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, XBOX.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    radioButtonps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cheatsactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PS.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}




}
```

**Update**
It now gives me 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference whenever i clicked on the radio button`

Im trying to change to make the user change the onclick listener for a button in main activty from the settings activity any solution?

Comment: All these radio buttons are declared in `R.layout.settings` xml? If possible, please share xml code.

Comment: yes i did declare them inside a radiogroup

Comment: Change the MainActivity.this to Settings.this In all Intent

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a *living* activitys context as the first parameter of `new Intent`.

Try changing `MainActivity.this` to `Settings.this` in your intents, e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, PC.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write `Settings.this` instead of `MainActivity.this` like @howdoidothis said. And I think you have mistakenly used `onClickListener` instead of `onCheckChangedListener`. See the following example:

```
rd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, PC.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First,
always follow re-usability because you have used Radio group and you applying intent from Radio button with another button click.

Once go with below code snippet,if still not work then update here,

```
radioGroup 
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

                if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
                    //some code
                     Intent intent = new Intent(Settings .this, PC.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
                    //some code
                     Intent intent = new Intent(Settings .this, XBOX.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton3) {
                    //some code
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings .this, PS.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: its gives me java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: Can you please clear where you will get  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick error ?

Comment: i fixed this it was caused by me not declaring settings activity now i get java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Have you declared button widget?
I don't think here you need button click event because all manages from radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                        if (i == radioButtonpc.getId()) {
                            //your code
                        }
                        if (i == radioButtonxx.getId()) {
                            //your code
                        }
                        if (i == radioButton.getId()) {
                            //your code
                        }
                        if (i == radioButtonab.getId()) {
                            //your code
                        }
                    }
                });
```